# How do I add indentation to bash tail?

Tags: bash, tail

When you do a tail on a long line a wrapping happens. However, when you are tailing a log it is important to see where one line ends and the other begins. So, is is possible in tail to create an identation? The wrapping, instead of starting on the column 0, would start in the column 10. For example:

```
this is a very long line to simulate how a line would wrap in a terminal window
suppose this is the wrapping and it is just the same line the continues here.
this is another very long line to simulate how a line would wrap in a terminal window
suppose this is the wrapping and it is just the same line the continues here.
```

versus

```
this is a very long line to simulate how a line would wrap in a terminal window
    suppose this is the wrapping and it is just the same line the continues here.
this is another very long line to simulate how a line would wrap in a terminal window
    suppose this is the wrapping and it is just the same line the continues here.
```

Please note that I am not trying to modify the way the line was saved to the log file, rather, to just display the line using a different format.

Comment: `cat` have `-n` and `-E` options to improve readability in that cases. Not exactly what was asked, but still useful.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just pipe tail to a formatter of your choice.  A simple perl script should work:

```
tail log-file | perl -pe 's/(.{80})/$1\n\t/g'
```

will indent lines with a tab character.  If you are doing `tail -f`, you'll probably want to minimize buffering with :

```
tail -f log-file | perl -pe '$|=1; s/(.{80})/$1\n\t/g'
```

Answer (score 2):

*If*:

- you're using *GNU* `fmt` (Linux) ...
- ... and a fixed indentation of *3 spaces* for wrapped lines is also acceptable
- ... and your log lines have at least 1 tab or space every N chars., where N is the default or chosen max. line width

try, e.g.:

```bash
tail -f log | fmt -t
```

- Breaks lines after a max. of 75 chars by default. To specify a custom width, use `-w`; e.g.: `-w 80`
- `fmt` will not split in the middle of words, which helps readability.
  Unfortunately, though, it won't split at all if there are no spaces or tabs.